# Firebase Authentication: get user information on backend

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to add Firebase authentication via standard UI to my node.js app.
On my login page I have added the following code:

```
// Initialize Firebase
var config = {
    apiKey: "...",
    authDomain: "...",
    databaseURL: "...",
    projectId: "...",
    storageBucket: "...",
    messagingSenderId: "..."
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

var ui = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(firebase.auth());

ui.start('#firebaseui-auth-container', {
    signInOptions: [
        // List of OAuth providers supported.
        firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        /*firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        firebase.auth.TwitterAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        firebase.auth.GithubAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID*/
    ],
    signInSuccessUrl: "firebase-login"
})
```

Up to here everything is fine. The "Login with Google", "Facebook" etc buttons are shown and after logging in (for example with Google) it takes me back to my login page and after a second I'm redirected to `firebase-login` as I specified in `signInSuccessUrl` parameter above.

Now, on my backed side I have the following:

```
app.get("/firebase-login", function(req, res){
    res.json("ok");
});
```

So how do I get formation about the logged in user in my `firebase-login` route? I need to do so in order to check if the user is already registered etc.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I made it.

On my client side I have to add a callback to the `ui.start` config to retrieve the idToken of the logged in user and post to backend, like this:

```
ui.start('#firebaseui-auth-container', {
    callbacks: {
        signInSuccessWithAuthResult: function(authResult, redirectUrl) {
            firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(/* forceRefresh */ true).then(function(idToken) {
                var form = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("form"));
                form.action = "/firebase-login";
                form.method = "POST";
                var input = form.appendChild(document.createElement("input"));
                input.type = "hidden";
                input.name = "idToken";
                input.value = idToken;
                form.submit();
            }).catch(function(error) {
                console.error(error);
            });
            return false;
        }
    }, ...
```

Then on my backed side I use `firebase-admin` to get user information from idToken posted by client side like this:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
var serviceAccount = require('path/to/serviceAccont.json');

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: "https://<MY-APP-ID>.firebaseio.com"
});

app.post("/firebase-login", function(req, res){
    admin.auth().verifyIdToken(req.body.idToken)
    .then(function(decodedToken) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(decodedToken));
    }).catch(function(error) {
        res.json(error);
    });
});
```

et voila! `decodedToken` contains all the information I need about the user (e.g. full name, email, picture url etc);